# Using tritium to move html elements

Tags: html, move, moovweb, tritium

I'm using the [Moovweb SDK](http://www.moovweb.com/developers/moovwebsdk) to make a mobile version of a website and I need to move an image from one div to another. How can I do this using tritium?

```
<body>
  <div class="kittens">
    <img src="images/husky.jpg" id="husky">
  </div>

  ...

  <div class="puppies">
    [need to move img here]
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.

The way I find most appealing is to use some XPath axes and the move_here command:

```
$("./body/div[contains(@class,'puppies')]") {
  move_here("ancestor::body/div[contains(@class,'kittens')]/img[@id='huskey']")
}
```

This way gets the same effect using fewer characters (but is slower):

```
$("//div[contains(@class,'puppies')]") {
  move_here("//img[@id='huskey']")
}
```

The reason I like doing it the first way is that, generally, the img you're looking for will not be so close to the body. Instead of doing the `ancestor::body` you could do `//img[@id=''huskey]` but this will likely be much slower. The other benefit to using ancestor is that it shows the connection between the two elements.

Answer (score 4):

You can either use move_to or move_here.

With move_to, it would look like this:

```
$("./div[contains(@class, 'kittens')]") {
  move_to("../div[contains(@class, 'puppies')]")
}
```

Test it live: http://play.tritium.io/311b7aad88ac174899dc4c2f7ebc7407db1ea08d